# Java: Style-Correcting Code: finding comment

Tags: java, find, styles, logic, comments

I'm writing these algorithms for a style-correcting program which makes adjustments to a java source file, that can compile without error. It is currently set to read the file line-by-line.

Right now, I'm having trouble writing 2 methods/algorithms which

1. Determine if the current line (string) has comments, and
2. finds where the comment starts

I currently have:

```
 public static int FindComment (String TextLine) {
              int EndOfCode = TextLine.lastIndexOf(";  ");
              return TextLine.indexOf("//", EndOfCode);

           }

        public static boolean HasComment (String TextLine) {
           if (TextLine.contains("//")) 
           {
              return true;
           }

           else
           {
              return false;
           }
        }
```

I know this is incorrect because I can have code, and comments, which contain " ; // ; //" as well as comments. I tried other conditional statements without success.

Comment: What about multi-line comment? - You should start thinking of getting a Java lexer.

Answer (score -1):

Hello you don't explain what problem do you have but I think you should escape with backslash characters when working with indexOf function.